# R.idへの文字列のひも付け方法について

Tags: android

intentでやりとりする情報からR.idを取るに当たって下記の様にHashMapで　"news" => R.id.menu_new　といった関連付けを行っているのですが、もっとスマートな方法はあるのでしょうか？
R.idをそのまま投げるやり方もあるのですが、外部とやり取りする際に文字列にするので結局変換が必要です。

```
static HashMap<String,Integer> menuIdTable = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
    {
        put("news", R.id.menu_news);
        put("message", R.id.menu_message);
        put("bookmark", R.id.menu_bookmark);
        put("ranking", R.id.menu_ranking);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resources.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) が用意されています。

以下のような形:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(strId, "id", getPackageName());
```

ユーティリティメソッドと使い方は以下のようになるでしょう:

```
static int string2Rid( Context cx, String strId) {

    return cx.getResources().getIdentifier( strId, "id", cx.getPackageName());

}

...
// Inside Activity
{
    final String receivedIdStr = "bookmark";

    ...

    final String menuIdStr = "menu_" + receivedIdStr;
    final int menuId = string2Rid(this, menuIdStr);
    if ( menuId == 0) throw DeathByDragonError(); 

    TextView targetView = (TextView)findViewById(menuId);

    ...
}
```